# Scrolling to specific page using pageControl and ScrollView ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I know this question has been asked earlier but i am not getting any specific answer to my problem. I am using page control and scrollView to add view controllers and then showing all the pages using swipe. I need to redirect to a particular page on button click. I tried scrollView SetcontentOffet and every other possiblities.

```
-(void)ScrollToPage:(int)page
{
 UIViewController *controller = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
 if (controller.view.superview == nil)
 {
      CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
      if (frame.size.width == 0)
      {
           frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
           frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
      }
      frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
      frame.origin.y = 0;
      controller.view.frame = frame;

      [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
      self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
      [self centerScrollViewContents];
      [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y)];
      [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
      [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the scroll view content size to match the width/height of the content? Also, calling setContentOffset and scrollRectToVisible together doesn't make sense, as they do pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your pages are using your device width closely. Just follow the below steps.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      self.myCurrentPage = 0;
      [self setScrollViewPages];
      self.scrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)setScrollViewPages {
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
       UIView *myPageView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRect) {self.view.frame.size.width * i
        + 10.0f,10.0f,self.view.frame.size.width - 20.0f , self.scrollView.frame.size.height-20.0f}];
       myPageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

       [self.scrollView addSubview:myPageView];

    }

}
```

On Button Clicked

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

//Pass the requried page, by default I'm passing 4
self.myCurrentPage = 4;
[self updateMyScrollView];
}
```

And the respective scroll view setting is

```
- (void)updateMyScrollView {
  [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width *self.myCurrentPage, 0) animated:YES];
  self.pageControl.currentPage = self.myCurrentPage;
}
```

Additionally, your scrollview delegate would be like this...

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
int pageWidth = self.view.frame.size.width ;
int pageX = self.myCurrentPage*pageWidth - scrollView.contentInset.left;
if (targetContentOffset->x<pageX) {
    if (self.myCurrentPage>0) {
        self.myCurrentPage--;
    }
}
else if(targetContentOffset->x>pageX){
    if (self.myCurrentPage < numerOfPages) {
        self.myCurrentPage++;
    }
}
targetContentOffset->x = self.myCurrentPage*pageWidth-scrollView.contentInset.left;
DLog(@"%ld %d", (long)self.myCurrentPage, (int)targetContentOffset->x);
self.pageControl.currentPage = self.myCurrentPage;
}
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: I am using the same method but still i am not able to achieve the desired result

Comment: what is the result you're getting by the above code?

Comment: when i am specifying any particular page to which i want to scroll , nothing is done. No scrolling and I didn't see the desired page